How to set labels properly in a sankey diagram created with ggsankey?
I have a problem how to label data in a sankey diagram created with the package "ggsankey".
# Import packages
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsankey)

# create data
test <- tibble(
  x = factor(c("Production", "Production", "Production", "Production", "Production", "Production", Transport", "Transport", "Consumption", "Consumption"),
             levels = c("Production", "Transport", "Consumption")),
  node = c("Product A", "Product B", "Product A", "Product B", "Product A", "Product B", "Transport", "Transport", "Sector I", "Sector II"),
  next_x = factor(c("Transport", "Transport", "Consumption", "Consumption", "Consumption", "Consumption", "Consumption", "Consumption", NA_character_, NA_character_),
                  levels = c("Production", "Transport", "Consumption", NA_character_)),
  next_node = c("Transport", "Transport", "Sector I", "Sector I", "Sector II", "Sector II", "Sector I", "Sector II", NA_character_, NA_character_),
  value = c(1323, 1159, 5070, 2554, 461, 2758, 1768, 713, 9392, 3932)
)

Use the value column from the data test to add flow value manually to the value aesthetic in the mapping:
# make sankey plot
ggplot(test, aes(x = x,
                 next_x = next_x,
                 node = node,
                 next_node = next_node,
                 value = value,
                 fill = factor(node),
                 label = factor(node))) +
  geom_sankey(flow.alpha = .6,
              color = "gray30") +
  geom_sankey_label(size = 3, color = "white", fill = "gray40") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(drop = FALSE) +
  theme_sankey(base_size = 18) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5)) +
  ggtitle("Massflow")

This produces the diagram with the correct flows and flow sizes, however the labelling is wrong:

On the left hand side, there should be only one label for the top three nodes, namely "Product B", and for the bottom three nodes, there should only be one label "Product A".
Use the following code, without assigning the value column in the data test to the value aesthetic in call to aes:
ggplot(test, aes(x = x,
                 next_x = next_x,
                 node = node,
                 next_node = next_node,
                 #value = value,
                 fill = factor(node),
                 label = factor(node))) +
  geom_sankey(flow.alpha = .6,
              color = "gray30") +
  geom_sankey_label(size = 3, color = "white", fill = "gray40") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(drop = FALSE) +
  theme_sankey(base_size = 18) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5)) +
  ggtitle("Massflow")


This produces the diagram with the correct flows and labelling, however, the size of the nodes in the last stage is wrong and also the flows between the nodes have the wrong size (all flows are equal):

So my question is: What am I missing here, to assign the labels correctly (as in plot 2) but with the correct size for the flows?

Here is a bit of a hacky option which uses the data used and computed under the hood to draw the nodes (which is the second layer) to add your desired labels using a geom_label. In general I would have expected that we can achieve the same result by setting the appropriate stat but unfortunately the Stats are not exported by ggsankey:
library(ggsankey)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(test, aes(
  x = x,
  next_x = next_x,
  node = node,
  next_node = next_node,
  value = value,
  fill = factor(node)
)) +
  geom_sankey(
    flow.alpha = .6,
    color = "gray30"
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(drop = FALSE) +
  theme_sankey(base_size = 18) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5)
  ) +
  ggtitle("Massflow")

p +
  geom_label(
    data = layer_data(p, i = 2),
    aes(x = x, y = .5 * (ymin + ymax), label = factor(node)),
    size = 3, color = "white", fill = "gray40",
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  labs(y = NULL)


